# FileManager always returns NO for file in caches directory?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I am trying to determine if a file exists in the Caches directory. I know for a fact the file in question exists in the caches directory, but the doesFileResideInCachesDirectory boolean always returns NO.

Why? This works for other directories (Documents etc)

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cachesDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *theFile = [cachesDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFile.png"];
BOOL doesFileResideInCachesDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:theFile];
```

Comment: How do you know for a fact that the file exists if `NSFileManager` says it doesn't?

Comment: By looking in the appropriate app sandbox folder. I copy the file there after the app launches and verify it's existence by loading/displaying an image

Comment: You display it in the app? And you logged the path to verify the location?

Comment: I have since fixed this. it appears that I was creating a subfolder folder inside the caches directory named "caches" and my file ended up inside that subfolder.